# Haskell recursive/circular module definitions?

Tags: haskell, types, module

I have two modules which imports each other. Haskell doesn't support recursive modules. So how can i rewrite my data types without needs circular module system.

Here is my Character.hs

```
module Character where
import ItemSystem

data Character = Character { name :: String, items :: [Item] }
```

an here is ItemSystem.hs

```
module Item where
import Character

data ItemEffect = CharacterEffect (Character -> Character)
                | ItemEffect      (Item -> Item)

data Item = Item { name :: String, weight :: Int, effect :: ItemEffect }
```

UPDATE: I will write my all datatypes into one module :( .

Comment: You could put them in one module

Comment: @AdamWagner ItemSystem is not simple as i wrote above so i need to split into two modules.

Comment: Note that GHC *does* support [some mutually recursive modules](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Mutually_recursive_modules).

Comment: By the way, Haskell allows mutually recursive modules, and GHC supports them, you need a `.hs-boot` module to get it going, though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Create a third module for the mutually dependent parts:

```
module Internal where

data Character = Character { name :: String, items :: [Item] }

data ItemEffect = CharacterEffect (Character -> Character)
                | ItemEffect      (Item -> Item)

data Item = Item { name :: String, weight :: Int, effect :: ItemEffect }
```

Then import it from both the other modules and optionally re-export the stuff you want available from each:

```
module Character (Character(..), {- etc -}) where

import Internal

-- non-mutually dependent stuff
```

```
module Item (Item(..), ItemEffect(..), {- etc -}) where

import Internal

-- non-mutually dependent stuff
```

If this is in a Cabal package, you can then hide the `Internal` module from the rest of the world by putting it in the `Other-modules` section instead of `Exported-modules`.

<sub>For completeness: [GHC does support mutually recursive modules](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/separate-compilation.html#mutual-recursion), but I would not recommend that for simple cases like this.</sub>

Comment: Thank you hammar. I guess your suggestion is better then .hs-boot file for this situation.

Comment: @hammar - great answer; I always enjoy finding answers to Haskell questions through Google; happens rarely, but happening more and more each day.

Answer (score 5):

Option 1: As hammar suggested, pull the mutually dependent parts into their own module.

Option 2: Put everything into the same module.

Option 3: If you're using GHC, you can create an [hs-boot](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/separate-compilation.html#mutual-recursion) file for one of your modules and have the other module import it with a `{-# SOURCE #-}` pragma.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use parameters... The `Character` is not a fixed type wrt to `Items`, but a parametric one.

```
module Character where

data BaseCharacter itemType = Character { name :: String, items :: [itemType] }
```

and `ItemSystem.hs` becomes

```
module Item where
import Character

type Character = BaseCharacter Item
data ItemEffect = CharacterEffect (Character -> Character)
                | ItemEffect      (Item -> Item)

data Item = Item { name :: String, weight :: Int, effect :: ItemEffect }
```